# CountIf returns 0 when criteria has decimal

Tags: vba

There is a range with the following values (0.1; 0.5; 1; 1.5)

If criteria value has a decimal (ex. 0.5), I can't get the right answer

VBA

```
Dim criteria As Double
criteria = 0.5

Cells(2, 2).Value = Application.CountIf(Range("c1:c4"), ">" & criteria) 'returns 0 (why?)

Cells(3, 2).Value = Application.CountIf(Range("c1:c4"), ">0.5") 'returns 2 (OK)
```

I need to understand why

Comment: I get two for both.

Comment: I'm using Excel in French. I tried with "." instead of a comma as the decimal separator but I still get the same result.

Comment: The values on the worksheet need to be in the local nomenclature, with the `,` as the decimal separator, but the vba must be `.` as vba is very US English centrist.

Comment: Instead of using CountIf, I made a loop to do the same job. I'm not sure if it will be as efficient though